# VMWare Fusion "unable to connect to proxy server" error

Tags: windows-8.1, vmware, fusion

I have been using VMWare Fusion 7.1.0 on my MacBook Pro with OSX Mavericks (10.9.5) without a hitch for several months. It was also working fine this morning until about an hour ago when I suddenly started getting an error message for any URL I tried: "Unable to connect to Proxy server."

I've tried both NAT and Bridged network adapters with no success.

There are no new software installs or updates (that I'm aware of), and I've tried restarted both the VM and the Mac itself twice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened, but my Network Proxy settings had gotten changed and set to use a manual proxy setup. I turned that off, and it resolved the error.

Here's how I found and fixed the settings:

1. Hit the Windows key (to get to the home page and do a text search)
2. Type "proxy" In the search results, click "Network proxy settings"
3. On the lower half of the screen under the Manual Proxy Setup, make sure the switch for "Use a proxy server" is turned OFF.

I'm doing web development in (primarily in Visual Studio Express 2013), so I wonder if the it jacked with my settings to allow for localhost development?

Answer (score 0):

Check your VM's OS networking settings and ensure auto-detect proxy settings is not enabled.